# How do you make a table like this with FPDF using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

How do you make a table like this with FPDF using PHP?

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with `$this->Cell`.

[image: Table]

Comment: I am open to using TCPDF, if it can be done there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FPDF does not recognize `rowspan` or `colspan`. Here is a workaround that you can try, using empty cells and the `border` attribute for [`Cell`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm).

```
$pdf->Cell(40,5,' ','LTR',0,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,top, and right borders
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'Words Here',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'Words Here',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(40,5,'Words Here','LR',1,'C',0);  // cell with left and right borders
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] abc',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] checkbox1',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(40,5,'','LBR',1,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,bottom, and right borders
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] def',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] checkbox2',1,0,'L',0);
```

and the result would be -
[image: fpdf table example]

Comment: Cell function do not wrap the contents of cell, if content length exceeds the width of cell the it flow away. Ugly affect if u have address and show using cell, then it will run away from page. did you know how t fix this? my be by using MultiCell?

Comment: This works, except the line breaks are in the wrong place, meaning where the row is supposed to stop and go to a new row, is wrong.  This is determined by the 5th value, where 1 is true (the next cell starts a new line) and 0 is false.  Another way to state it is when the 5th value is 1, that cell is the end of the row, so the 3rd line in the above code should read $pdf->Cell(50,5,'Words Here',1,1,'L',0);

Answer (score 5):

I think i found other solution, here is my solution without empty cell needed.

```
$pdf->Cell(40,18,'Words Here', 1,0, 'C');
$x = $pdf->GetX();
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'Words Here', 1,0);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'Words Here', 1,1);
$pdf->SetX($x);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'[x] abc', 1,0);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'[x] Checkbox 1', 1,1);
$pdf->SetX($x);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'[x] def', 1,0);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'[x] Checkbox 1', 1,1);
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, that helped, this worked for me:

```
$this->Cell(40,5,' ','LTR',0,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,top, and right borders
$this->Cell(50,5,'111 Here',1,0,'L',0);
$this->Cell(50,5,'222 Here',1,0,'L',0);

                $this->Ln();

$this->Cell(40,5,'Solid Here','LR',0,'C',0);  // cell with left and right borders
$this->Cell(50,5,'[ o ] che1','LR',0,'L',0);
$this->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] che2','LR',0,'L',0);

                $this->Ln();

$this->Cell(40,5,'','LBR',0,'L',0);   // empty cell with left,bottom, and right borders
$this->Cell(50,5,'[ x ] def3','LRB',0,'L',0);
$this->Cell(50,5,'[ o ] def4','LRB',0,'L',0);

                $this->Ln();
                $this->Ln();
                $this->Ln();
```