# HTML to PDF conversion rowspan not working

Tags: php, html, html-table, fpdf

I am using third party code for **HTML To PDF conversion** is working good.But this cannot accept ***rowspan why***?? Here is my code.

```
require('WriteHTML.php');
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>Title</h1>');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 

$htmlTable="<TABLE border='1'>

<TR height='40'>
<TD>S.NO</TD>
<TD>Type Of Beneficiary</TD>
<TD>Expected</TD>
<TD>No.Of Beneficiary</TD>
<TD>No.Of Packs Issued</TD>
<TD>Ave.monthly Usage</TD>
<TD>Balance Stock Available</TD>
</TR>

 <TR>
 <TD>1</TD>
 <TD>Adolescents Girls</TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD ></TD>
 </TR>

  <TR>
  <TD rowspan='4'>2</TD>
  <TD>Normal</TD>
  <TD>ALLOTMENT NO</TD>
  <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD rowspan='4'></TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
   <TD>LSCS</TD>
   <TD>ALLOTMENT NO</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
   <TD>Puperial Sterilization</TD>
   <TD>ALLOTMENT NO</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
  <TD>Total</TD>
  <TD>ALLOTMENT NO</TD>
  <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
  <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
  <TD>QUANTITY</TD>
  </TR>

 <TR>
 <TD>3</TD>
 <TD>Women Prison Inmates</TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>4</TD>
 <TD>Women IMH Inmates</TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>

 <TD>5</TD>
 <TD>Total</TD>
 <TD> </TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 <TD></TD>
 </TR>



 </TABLE>";
 $pdf->WriteHTML2("$htmlTable"); 
 $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Please tell us what pdf library you are using. Chances are they just don't support it.

Comment: it's including two files one is fpdf.php,writeHTML.php and css, js,but it's fpdf library

Comment: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-fpdf_447.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems FPDF doesn't support `rowspan`:

> **FPDF does not recognize rowspan** or colspan. Here is a workaround that
>   you can try, using empty cells and the border attribute for Cell.

by [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/689579/sean) (emphasis mine) - [here is the full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13411401/982075)

Comment: both links does'not work..please refer any other links??

Comment: You need to use the workaround provided in the link. You can't just *enable* rowspan or the like. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Rowspan and Colspan supporting the TCPDF Library.And also easy configration this one. Library path http://www.tcpdf.org/ and coding path http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps. just change the path only.     require_once('tcpdf.php');