# How I set the FPDF Cell to Right Side

Tags: php, fpdf

I have following table, it starts from left side but i need this table to start from right side.

```
$pdf->Cell(30,10,'Address Line 1',1,0,'R'); 
//this code align text Right Side not the cell i need to move the cell on right sie
-------------------------  -------------------------
|  Address Line 1          |       Version         |
|  Address Line 2          |         1.0           |
|  City                    |       06/05/2011      | 
-------------------------  -------------------------
```

requirement:

```
                                -------------------------  -------------------------
                                |  Address Line 1          |       Version         |
                                |  Address Line 2          |         1.0           |
                                |  City                    |       06/05/2011      | 
                                -------------------------  -------------------------
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407085/how-do-you-make-a-table-like-this-with-fpdf-using-php it can be help

Answer (score 1):

issue resolved. I applied the left Margin

```
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(85);
```