# How to put my for loop data inside on text wrap fpdf

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, codeigniter, fpdf

I want to make and output like this.

[image]

Im refering on this one, but i want to put my loop data inside the text warp and the template still remains. How to do it? here is my loop data inside from the function.

[How do you make a table like this with FPDF using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407085/how-do-you-make-a-table-like-this-with-fpdf-using-php)

```
$this->Cell(18,7,$data,1,0,'L');
    if ($count%2 == 0) {
        $this->Ln();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a table like this with FPDF using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407085/how-do-you-make-a-table-like-this-with-fpdf-using-php)

Comment: The question you linked to has the solution based on the information you've provided.